# passing values into a lightbox

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, lightbox

I need help passing values into a lightbox to displays shopping cart information.

Currently i have a simple setup just displaying a static sentence.

**Javascript Code:**

```
function displayHideBox(boxNumber) 
{ 
    if(document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display=="none") {
        document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("grayBG").style.display="block"; 
    } else { 
        document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("grayBG").style.display="none"; 
    } 
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<a href="<?$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?action=add&id=<?=$id;?>" onclick="displayHideBox('1'); return false;">Open Box</a>

<div id="grayBG" class="grayBox" style="display:none;"></div> 
<div id="LightBox1" class="box_content" style="display:none;"> 
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0"> 
  <tr align="left"> 
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding:10px;"><div onclick="displayHideBox('1'); return false;" style="cursor:pointer;" align="right">X</div><p><!-- Box content -->Text of the box!!!</p></td> 
  </tr> 
</table> 
</div>
```

i have set up a simple shopping cart and currently when you add a product it goes to the shopping cart page where it creates a session and displays your items in your cart with options to remove or continue shopping. But when you add an item to your cart i need it to display a light box showing that items info and other items in shopping cart.

**here is the code currently for the "add to cart" feature:**

```
<table border="1">

    <?php
        //Select all of the relevant part details
        $prod_query = 'SELECT * FROM *****.*****';
        $prod_details = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $prod_query);                       
        $count = count($prod_details);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
            {?>         
             <tr>
                <? $id = $prod_details[$i]['catID'];?>
                 <td><?=$prod_details[$i]['catID'];?></td>
                 <td><?=$prod_details[$i]['shortDescription'];?></td>
                 <td><?=$prod_details[$i]['rrp'];?></td>
                 <td><a href="cart.php?action=add&id=<?=$id;?>">Add To Cart</a></td>

             </tr>
        <?}?>
</table>


<a href="cart.php">View Cart</a>
```

So really I think my question is how do i get this dynamic data into my lightbox?

i hope i have explained this well enough and that someone can help me...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible option would be to use a global object within Javascript to store entries in your cart. You can do this by creating a variable such as 'var cartArr=[];' in your javascript, and then when an item is added to the cart write a function that updates the cartArr variable. Then just reference that within the lightbox.

**Please note that this is untested, and is meant as an example of one possible way to access from a lightbox. Also note that you would need to add the functions to verify if the item was already in the cart and then increment, as well as to remove from the cart.

Hope it helps.

```
    <?php
            //Select all of the relevant part details
            $prod_query = 'SELECT * FROM *****.*****';
            $prod_details = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $prod_query);                       
            $count = count($prod_details);
            for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
                {?>         
                 <tr>
                    <? $id = $prod_details[$i]['catID'];?>
                     <td><?=$prod_details[$i]['catID'];?></td>
                     <td><?=$prod_details[$i]['shortDescription'];?></td>
                     <td><?=$prod_details[$i]['rrp'];?></td>
                     <td><a href="cart.php?action=add&id=<?=$id;?>">Add To Cart</a></td>
                echo "
                <script type=\"text/javascript\">
                var cartitem = {id:$prod_details[$i]['catID'], desc:$prod_details[$i]['shortDescription'], rrp:$prod_details[$i]['rrp']};
               addToCartJs(cartitem);
                </script>
            ";
                 </tr>
            <?}?>
```

====js

```
var cartArr = [];

function addToCartJs(item){
  cartArr.push(item);
}
```

===appended

```
    function setCartDisplay(boxNumber){
        var itemdisplay = '';
        for(var i=0; i<cartArr.length;i++){
            var itemdisplay = '<span class="cartdisplay">ItemNo:'+cartArr[i].id+'</span>';
            itemdisplay += '<span class="cartdisplay">Description:'+cartArr[i].desc+'</span>';
        }
        document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).innerHTML = itemdisplay;
    }
```

===testing page===
Use this to test and display the information and what it is doing... this is a great learning opportunity. Remember, it is better to learn and understand your code for future additions and maintenance. "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"

```
<div id="LightBox1" class="box_content" style="display:none;"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var cartArr = [];

function testCartItem(){
    var cartitem = {id:1001, desc:'description here', rrp:1002 };
    addToCartJs(cartitem);
}

function addToCartJs(item){
  cartArr.push(item);
} 

function setCartDisplay(boxNumber){
    var itemdisplay = '';
    for(var i=0; i<cartArr.length;i++){
        var itemdisplay = '<span class="cartdisplay">ItemNo:'+cartArr[i].id+'</span><br>';
        itemdisplay += '<span class="cartdisplay">Description:'+cartArr[i].desc+'</span>';
    }
    document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).innerHTML = itemdisplay;
    document.getElementById("LightBox"+boxNumber).style.display="block";
}

testCartItem();
console.log(cartArr);
setCartDisplay(1);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer most of it makes sense to me but your code has confused me somewhat. I understand that you take the data from the database and push it into a javascript array. how do I then take this array and display it within my lightbox? as currently it just displays a static sentence

Comment: I have appended an example of a possilbe way of accessing the cartArr within the light box. As the object is javascript, we will need to display with javascript (or jQuery). Add a div or span to the lightbox/each lightbox instance, and then populate similar to the appended example above. Hope that helps

Comment: thanks again. To be honest im not sure what to do with your code im not experienced enough with this. I've put all javascript into a seperate file i hope this is ok. but I dont really know how to use the code you gave me

Comment: I have added some script to assist you in creating a testing page to see what the code is doing. This is an excellent learning tool to understand the  methods and what they are doing in the event that you need to look at in the future. Good luck.

Comment: thankyou that looks good to me I think I understand it but im just tinkering with it now to get the desired effect...thanks for your help :)